# How can I get the longitude and latitude in my app without google map API?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, location, maps

In my Android app, I have a signup form in which I want the user to choose a location on the map so that I can have the longitude and latitude of the selected location.
I don't want to use Maps API. rather I want some way to use Google Map app for picking up the location. and go back to my app with the selected location data.
Although I don't know if this is the [right/possible] way of doing this.
After doing hours of research I found there are many SDKs for the same but I want some easy method since it is just a one-time process.

Answer (score 0):

You can open google maps with the help of intent and then from there let the user select the  desire location.
After user done with the location you have comeback to your App's MainActivity and inside
`onActivityResult()` method you'll get your desire result.

Comment: I don't know which Intent to use. it would be a great help if you could show me code for the same.